# What is the significance of Ehud hiding the sword on his right thigh in Judges 3:21?

Tags: judges

Judges 3:21

> Ehud reached with his left hand, drew the sword from his right thigh and plunged it into the king's belly.

Couldn't he have achieved the same goal by hiding it on his left thigh?

Comment: There is a significance. See also the warriors who could sling a stone at a hair with their left hand. I see the significance as a matter of faith. The right hand is the natural hand of strength. The left is (in allusion) not a matter of the strength of a man, but the guidance of God. This is an interpretation, cannot be 'proved' and so is a comment, not an answer. (+1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ehud, a Left-Handed Man](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26555/ehud-a-left-handed-man)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is a practical one on Judges 3.  If a sword is strapped to the right side it cannot be drawn by the right hand.  Similarly, if a sword is strapped to the left side it cannot be drawn by the left hand.  In order to draw a sword, on usually reaches across the stomach to withdraw a sword.

This was Ehud's advantage - he was left-handed and the king would not suspect there being a sword on the right.

Note Benson's comment in V16:

> His right thigh — Which was most convenient both for the use of his
> left hand, and for avoiding suspicion.

Comment: This is my understanding of the passage. It would be nice to see a historical military description, however. Benson's commentary (and others) can be found at https://biblehub.com/commentaries/judges/3-16.htm